# Javascript convert Date() to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Is there a simple way to convert a date object for the current time into `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format? I've tried `new Date().toLocaleString()` but that gives me a human readable date.

What are my options using jquery or javascript in order to do this?

Comment: No, there's not, you'd do `date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + ...` etc

Comment: You can use moment.js library. It has easy way to do this. otherwise, no easy way same as @adeneo said.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately using plain JavaScript you don't have a really quick way to do that. 
If you are going to struggle with dates a lot, my suggestion is to include the `moment.js` library to your project, which will allow you do that really easily.
In this way for example you can output the current date in the specified format:

`moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // May 14th 2017, 4:50:42 pm`

Here the link to the moment.js library:

https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Recommending a library should be a comment, not an answer. There are many such libraries, e.g. [*fecha.js*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fecha).